# Event for user creation in administration

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, user, administrator

Is there an event like `onUserCreation()` for the **backend** in J3? So if an administrator creates a new user, specified code (e. g. from plugin) is executed. In the [API guides](https://docs.joomla.org/API_Guides) I didn't find any obviously relevant content for this. Do you know if there's any event like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onUserAfterSave` event, which also includes a `isnew` argument, like so:

```
public function onUserAfterSave($user, $isnew, $success, $msg)
{
    if ($isnew && $success)
    {
        // A new user was created and successully stored in the database.
        // Perform some action
    }
}
```

Comment: And this method is valid for the backend as well?

Comment: @alve89, yes, both backend and frontend